# How to Escape special characters during insertion in python-mysql?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am scraping some data-points from a webpage using python and storing it into list. Now i want to store this list into different columns of the table.

The data i am pulling is having some special character which is creating some obvious issue during insertion.

Sample Data:

```
Datapoint 1: 2014-07-07_7-41-49
Datapoint 2: generic
Datapint 3: 19
Datapoint 4: en_us
Datapoint 5: 70587htyuipp
Datapoint 6: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
google_sdk0.SizeRange.smallest=[800,727]
```

Code Snippet

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","username","password","database")
var_string = ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in a) # a is the list of the datapoints
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO error_report VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" % (var_string))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

P.S. Datapoint 6 is the main culprit, it might contain quote, comma and other special character.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: Specifically, use your DB API to properly escape the special characters by passing your parameters to it in the format it expects (a tuple of values) rather than relying on string interpolation to build the query string.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've often used `','.join('?' * len(params))` to generate a correct number of placeholders when inserting variable numbers of values.  Avoiding SQL Injection is worth your time, most assuredly.